# Comparing files in the different directory using bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, loops, mv

I've created a script wherein it will compare the two files in different directory (`rpms` and `newrpms`). This two directory composed of files. in the `rpms/` side it was the old version files and in the `newrpms/` is the updated ones. So in this script, the main goal for this is that the files inside the directory will be compared, if there are same name files remove the older one and replace it with the updated file.

`rpms/` -- the files inside of this directory

```
firefox-24.5.0-1.el5_10.i386.rpm
firefox-24.5.0-1.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-src-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.7.0-openjdk-debuginfo-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
```

`newrpms/` -- the updated files that needs to replace the old ones in the `rpms/` directory

```
firefox-25.5.0-1.el5_10.i386.rpm
firefox-25.5.0-1.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-demo-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
java-1.6.0-openjdk-src-1.6.0.0-5.1.13.3.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
```

Please see belows script.

```
for i in $(\ls -d ./rpms/*);
do diff ${i} newrpms/; 
done
```

For the code above, nothing happens. Can anyone help me to solve my problem. All I want is to compare the two directory and get the the same files if and only if in the `rpms/` directory don't have the same files that `newrpms/` have it is very understandable to move it from the `newrpms/` to `rpms/` nad if ever that they have the same filename but have just little part are not the same. Check it the most updated one.
ex.

```
firefox-24.5.0-1.el5_10.i386.rpm --> in the rpms/
firefox-25.5.0-1.el5_10.i386.rpm --> in the newrpms/
```

so the most updated one is in the `newrpms/`. remove the `firefox-24.5.0-1.el5_10.i386.rpm` in the `rpms/` and move the `firefox-25.5.0-1.el5_10.i386.rpm` into `rpms/`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know what is going wrong with your script. Are you sure there are differences between the rmps in the new and old directory? Have you tried the `-s` option for `diff` that will report identical files?

But in any case, the script is too complicated for the task you are trying to perform. This should be the equivalent command:

```
diff rpms newrpms
```

If there are files in one directory that do not exist in the other, that will be noted in the output. And differences in binary files will also reported.  But you probably don't even need to do that. Why not use the `cp` command to simply copy files from `newrpms` to `rpms`? Or, if you want to be more sophisticated, use `rsync`:

```
rsync -av newrpms rpms
```

That will check to see if any file in `newrpms` is newer than the one in `rpms` and only perform the copy when needed. (Check out `man rsync` for more details.)

Comment: hi sir, thank you for your response. but, I supposedly need to compare the files character by character. Is it okay to put it in an array ? What do you think ?

Comment: You probably don't want to use an array and `diff` won't do the trick either. Try `cmp` instead. But are you _sure_ that's what you need? Have you looked at `rsync`?

Comment: not yet I will try it on.

Comment: I think sir, I don't  `rsync`. because it is not appropriate to what should I want to do.

Comment: how can I compare the files in the directory sir, character per character cause it is so tricky to have those kind of files.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a new question. That's not what you asked in this one.

Comment: I think you mean `diff -r rpms newrpms`. And I always add `-u` to make the output legible ☺